# Android How to zoom in 3x equivalent in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, zooming

I am working on a custom app where I want to zoom in on an imageview overlayed over a camera view in Andorid.
What I want to do, when I double tap on the screen, I want to zoom in exactly 3x on camera and equivalent zoom on the ImageView

I am using ImageViewTouch library for zooming in on double tap.

How can I zoom in to a ImageView, equivalent to a 3x zoom on cameraview ?

Comment: why don't you try pinch zooming so the user can control how bigger the image he want.

Comment: Well, that is not the requirement.:) But how can zoom to an ImageView equivalent to a zoom level in Camera like 3x zoom for example?

Comment: I'll post a code and try to use it

Comment: I'd posted a codes. Hope that it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this codes. It will 3x the size of the image by clicking a button.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    View mainView = null;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      mainView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

      Button buttonZoomIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonZoomIn);



      buttonZoomIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
        zoom(3f,3f,new PointF(0,0));   
       }
      });
     }

     /** zooming is done from here */
     public void zoom(Float scaleX,Float scaleY,PointF pivot){
      mainView.setPivotX(pivot.x);
      mainView.setPivotY(pivot.y);  
      mainView.setScaleX(scaleX);
      mainView.setScaleY(scaleY);  
     } 
    }
```